# How to replace HABTM associations with array from frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Rails 7 API coupled with a NuxtJS frontend. I have view and edit pages for various resources on the frontend. For a few resources, I have tagging.

I can handle both adding end removing associations (tags) one by one, however, I’d like to make it possible to edit them in a bundle. That is, on the relevant edit (and create) views I would have an interface to add and remove tags, then once the user hits the save button, the removed (if any) tags get removed, the newly added (if any) ones get added to the resource.

Currently, I’m using the following syntaxes: `@article.tags << @tag` and `@article.tags.delete(@tag)`. This works as expected for both scenarios.

My thinking goes as follows: I should be able to pass an array of ids of tags, do something like `@article.tags = @tags`. However, this does not seem to delete the relevant rows in the join tables.

Is there a way to do this properly, “the Rails way”?

Comment: It should replace them. What shows up in your `log/development.log` when you try?

Comment: you can use nested attributes for that. here is a doc for getting started: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html